# Beautiful Soup: List Index Out of Range even when code says [0]

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How do i fix this error (Web Scraping)

```
import requests

standings_url = "https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/Premier-League-Stats"
data = requests.get(standings_url)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time


soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)

standings_table = soup.select('table.stats_table')[0]

links = standings_table.find_all('a')
links = [l.get("href") for l in links]
links = [l for l in links if '/squads/' in l]

team_urls = [f"https://fbref.com{l}" for l in links]
data = requests.get(team_urls[0])

matches = pd.read_html(str(data.text), match="Scores & Fixtures")[0]

soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text)

links = soup.find_all('a')
links = [l.get("href") for l in links]
links = [l for l in links if l and 'all_comps/shooting/' in l]

data = requests.get(f"https://fbref.com{links[0]}")
shooting = pd.read_html(str(data.text), match="Shooting")[0]

shooting.columns = shooting.columns.droplevel()

team_data = matches.merge(shooting[["Date", "Sh", "SoT", "Dist", "FK", "PK", "PKatt"]], on="Date")

years = list(range(2023, 2020, -1))
all_matches = []

standings_url = "https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/Premier-League-Stats"

for year in years:
    data = requests.get(standings_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text)
    standings_table = soup.select('table.stats_table')[0]

    links = [l.get("href") for l in standings_table.find_all('a')]
    links = [l for l in links if '/squads/' in l]
    team_urls = [f"https://fbref.com{l}" for l in links]

    previous_season = soup.select("a.prev")[0].get("href")
    standings_url = f"https://fbref.com{previous_season}"

    for team_url in team_urls:
        team_name = team_url.split('/')[-1].replace("-Stats", "").replace("-", " ")
        data = requests.get(team_url)
        matches = pd.read_html(str(data.text), match="Scores & Fixtures")[0]
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text)
        links = [l.get("href") for l in soup.find_all('a')]
        links = [l for l in links if l and 'all_comps/shooting/' in l]
        data = requests.get(f"https://fbref.com{links[0]}")
        shooting = pd.read_html(str(data.text), match="Shooting")[0]
        shooting.columns = shooting.columns.droplevel()
        try:
            team_data = matches.merge(shooting[["Date", "Sh", "SoT", "Dist", "FK", "PK", "PKatt"]], on="Date")
        except ValueError:
            continue

        team_data["Season"] = year
        team_data["Team"] = team_name
        all_matches.append(team_data)
        time.sleep(1)
        break

match_df = pd.concat(all_matches)
match_df.columns = [c.lower() for c in match_df.columns]

match_df.to_csv("matches.csv")
print(match_df)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\WebScrapingEPL\EPL webscrape.py", line 48, in <module>
    standings_table = soup.select('table.stats_table')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Trying to extract match logs of the past few years for all premier league teams. Received an error related to beautiful soup. Can someone help me resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely because the returned **list is empty**.

When you are unsure whether the list will be empty or not, you can do the following:

```py
standings_table = soup.select('table.stats_table')

if standings_table:  # Check whether the list exists and only after access it's elements
    standings_table = standings_table[0]
```

Hope this helps!